# Input variable created at Main is a different value to that created in Method

Tags: java

I have created a method that gets input from the user. However, my issue is that when I attempt to return the value of the method, it continuously asks for a new number as input. Instead, I want it to ask for a number once, then return it.

For example: the following code illustrates what I want to achieve without a method, but including it within a method causes difficulties:

Working Code Inside Main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int age;

     System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
     age = input.nextInt();

     System.out.print("/nYou're " + age + " years of age.");
  }
```

However, when I try to do this within a method, I have difficulties:

Code Inside Method:

```
  public static int getAge() { 
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number; 

      number = input.nextInt()
      return number;
    }
```

The issue is, whenever I try print System.out.print(getAge()); it asks for a number each time. Why does the first code allow me to print age without asking for a new number, but calling the method to print the number causes issues and continues to ask for a new number.

Effectively, I just want to call that method, ask for a number to input once, then call that method to return the number that the user has entered.

Comment: You need to store the user input in a variable if you like to return that instead of asking the user again.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What difficulties do you have?

Comment: @Baleroc Before I do that, may I ask you what you're trying to achieve? For example, if you like to create a `Person` class with for example a `name` and an `age`, then there are same ways to solve that, but if you just like to have a single method with no connection to a _model_ class, then there are other ways to do it. So can you explain what your goal is?

Comment: I have difficulties of having a method to get a number through user input then return that number through the method. Except every time I do this, it is asking for a new number. For example, if I call System.out.print("Enter Age: ); then I would call getAge(); to get the number. However, once I have that number, I want to be able to print it such as, System.out.print("your age is " + getAge() + " years of age"); but instead this is prompting the user again for another number.

Comment: So you only want the age of a user? No name or any other info you like to "combine" into on single `User` instance? So you want do something like `User currentUser = new User(); currentUser.setAge(getAge());`?

Comment: Here are the steps: (1) Ask user for age (2) Call getAge() method to allow user to input age (3) Once age has had input, then I want to be able to call the method to return the value of age. (4) Be able to call getAge() to return the value of the person's age.

Comment: Ah ok. Then you can use the code that @MaxZoom has posted in his answer. Btw: you can edit your question to add these 4 steps to it, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not just about having code to do job, but also about design. I would recommend below approach, features are:

- A utility class and a generic method `promptUserInput` to prompt the user for input, passing your message
- It will return a String object, convert it into other objects as required.
- If you want to access it from other methods/classes, then store as instance variable, else simply use it to print or whatever is your plan.

You can handle the Scanner object to close it once everything is done, and parent thread is ready to die, for that you will need some change.

P.S.: My intention is not simply providing chunk of codes but make you think how to design. So, you may need to some change as per your requirement, scenarios and as you test.

**Code:**

```
public class UserTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.promptUserAge();
        user.printUserAge(user.getUserAge());
        //DO something.
        user.printUserAge(user.getUserAge());
        user.promptUserAge();
        user.printUserAge(user.getUserAge());
    }
}

public class User {
    private int userAge = 0;

    public void promptUserAge() {
        String userInput = AppUtils.promptUserInput("Enter Age: ");
        userAge = new Integer(userInput);
    }

    public int getUserAge(){
        return userAge;
    }

    public void printUserAge(int age){
        System.out.print("\nYou're " + age + " years of age.");
    }
}

public class AppUtils {
    public static String promptUserInput(String message) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println(message);
        String userInput = input.next();
        return userInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this code should be used anywhere where a programmer likes to get user input: try it yourself ... call your method twice and see what happens.

Comment: @hagrawal I don't know how to apply this correctly for the following reason: I want a method to print out the number that the user has entered as input. I want to call a method to **only** return the number that the user has Inputted. So how I want it: I want one method to get the input from the user once the method is called, and another method to return the number the user has entered each time it's called.

Comment: Example: a method getAge() has number =  input.nextInt, return input. Method printAge() I want this method to now return the value stored in getAge without asking for another number to be entered. Similar to: System.out.print("Enter Age : "); getAge(); - this method gets user input. System.out.print("Your age: "); printAge(); - this method prints **only** the value of the age. So each time I use printAge() the number will be printed.

Comment: @Tom I accept that it will fail 2nd time, but my intention was to give a heads-up and make them think how to design because that's what is most important, but not to give a full-fledged working thread-safe solution. We can even go one step further and think if it is thread-safe, but that's not intention. If a person has came this far, then he surely can resolve these issues. It will fail second time because I am closing input stream.

Comment: I'm not talking about stuff like "thread-safe". Closing a `Scanner` which reads from `System.in` in a method that is supposed to be called several times, is (at least in my eyes) a major design flaw. But that's also the only point I worried about. The rest of the answer is very helpful.

Comment: @Tom Thanks. I will keep it as part of my lessons learned, after all each time we learn something :)

Comment: Good idea :). Closing `System.in` is always a bit tricky :D. But closing a `Scanner` with another resource (and not `System.in`) is a good idea and mostly correct.

Comment: @hagrawal Is it possible to remove the global variable userAge, and have that stored in the method promptUserAge(), then return the value of this variable that can be passed through to printUserAge(), such as printUserAge(int ageNumber) - pass the value of userAge created in promptUserAge() to another method printUserAge(int ageNumber) - is this also a possibility without having any global variables?

Comment: @Baleroc It is not possible to store the values in method, method variables are local and will live on stack only till method is getting executed, once method execution is completed, they will be removed and cannot be accessed. So, if you want some value of method to be available after method execution, then you have make its scope global by making setting it in instance variable or static variable or ThreadLocal etc. Looking the way you want, we can do something like - see edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the user input in a class member variable, and reuse it later on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    private int age = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.getAge();
        System.out.print("\nYou're " + o.getAge() + " years of age.");
    }

    public int getAge() { 
        if (age == -1) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
            age = input.nextInt();
        }
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, there is no difference between the OP's `getAge()` and your `getAge()`

Comment: That is correct. Number was a random variable name I added in getAge to prevent confusion, but effectively it's the same concept.

Comment: Edited. I would appreciate any votes whenever applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that every time you call `getAge()` it is going to create a new scanner and try to get input again. Instead, when you return your number from `getAge()` the first time, save the value in a variable that you can reuse.

Something like this:

```
int age = getAge();
System.out.print("your age is " + age + " years of age");
```